# AWS CDK Conditional Stage Deployments

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have a bit of a challenge here.  So, I am using AWS pipelines pretty extensively to do deployments and maintain 50 different deployments in an environment.  I have things replicated across multiple accounts / regions using different pipelines.  But, I need to start adding some conditional statements into the deployments to either deploy/not deploy a stage in a pipeline depending on environment readiness (think bootstrapping / setup vs long-term running).

So, am trying to find a way in my pipeline to add cfnCondition statements to a stage definition to not add the stage to the pipeline until the environment is ready.  I have a stage / script that does a ton of infrastructure setup so don't want the stages runing until that stuff is done.  Found this article (https://loige.co/create-resources-conditionally-with-cdk/#using-cfncondition-with-cdk) but 1. cannot find a level 0 construct for a stage and 2. does not seem to like this in cdk v2 / errors on cfnOptions.

Anyone have an option for this so I can get this from SSM / make conditional statements in my stage definitions(btw, if i do this within the project / static local file it works fine, need this from ssm / parameter store so that I can release other pipelines once setups are done).

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Conditionality would be a challenging workaround, as @lynkfox says.  Instead, why not have the Pipeline wait until the environment statbilises?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple to achive. You can pass SSM Params to the whole Pipeline by specifying the CodeBuild Environment (where synth is done). [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable.html) You can look into the documentation. In the pipeline itself You can refer to this variable like this:

```js
if(process.env.MY_SSM_VAR==='myFancyInput'){
   pipeline.addMyConditionalStage()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned: Parameter Store is very useful for this - For any concept that is in every pipeline, but the value changes (ie: the name of the Lambda, or the endpoint for this api) this is very useful.

However, note, Pipelines cannot do If X then Y sort of deals - It is always going to be "Step 1, Step 2, Step 3..." ect ect.  - Never "Step 1, then If A, Step 2 Else Step 2.5"

If you have things that are very conditional that depend on other actions, your best bet is to create a Step Function that handles all these things and call it as part of your Pipeline.